# Salvar data e hora no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Gostaria de saber se tem como eu salvar a data e hora do meu sistema para poder salvar no banco de dados, eu não gostaria de criar um "criado_em" e adicionar a hora no banco, o que eu quero fazer é mais "complexo" acredito eu, estou tentando aqui mas não obtive sucesso.

**O que quero salvar**

```
$emailarquivo = $_POST['email'].$_POST['datetime'];
$nome_final = $emailarquivo;
```

**Como vou inserir no banco**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO contato (`nome`,`caminho`) VALUES ('".$nome_final."', '".$_UP['pasta']."')";
```

Eu já tentei com o nome no lugar do datetime e funciona, ele envia o nome e o e-mail na mesma coluna, mas como faria para passar a data e hora?

Comment: pra que serve $nome_final = $emailarquivo; porque não VALUES ('".$emailarquivo."', Agora diga como é passado esse datetime, cade o HTML

Comment: É pra eu conseguir organizar melhor, usamos um padrão onde eu trabalho. Então o datetime não é passado, eu gostaria de saber se existe algum modo de pegar o do sistema, o datetime é só um "exemplo" de como seria.

Comment: Já consegui, eu não preciso pegar os dados de um $_POST

Comment: estranho então esse $_POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Solução* :**

**Alterar**

```
$emailarquivo = $_POST['email'].$_POST['datetime'];
```

**Para**

```
$emailarquivo = $_POST['email'].$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: isso ai, o $_post confundiu o entendimento da pergunta

Comment: Sim, é que sempre que trato dados que pego do cliente ou algum outro lugar normalmente uso o $post..